# String_replace replaces not all elements

Tags: php, str-replace

I am making a Laravel Helper function, that should convert ":)" and others to normal smiles, however, some elements just do not convert! Maybe you can help me to find that, maybe stupid, mistake.

Code:

```
public static function convertSmiles($string)
{
    $smiles = [
        ':)',
        ':angel:',
        ':angry:',
        '8-)',
        ':\'(',
        ':ermm:',
        ':D',
        '<3',
        ':(',
        ':O',
        ':P',
        ';)',
        ':alien:',
        ':blink:',
        ':blush:',
        ':cheerful:',
        ':devil:',
        ':dizzy:',
        ':getlost:',
        ':happy:',
        ':kissing:',
        ':ninja:',
        ':pinch:',
        ':pouty:',
        ':sick:',
        ':sideways:',
        ':silly:',
        ':sleeping:',
        ':unsure:',
        ':woot:',
        ':wassat:'
    ];
    $urls = [
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/smile.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/angel.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/angry.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/cool.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/cwy.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/ermm.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/grin.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/heart.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/sad.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/shocked.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/tongue.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/wink.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/alien.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/blink.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/blush.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/cheerful.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/devil.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/dizzy.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/getlost.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/happy.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/kissing.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/ninja.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/pinch.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/pouty.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/sick.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/sideways.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/silly.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/sleeping.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/unsure.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/w00t.png'/>",
        "<img src='".url('/jquery/sceditor/emoticons')."/wassat.png'/>"
    ];
    return str_replace($smiles,$urls,$string);
}
```

I have problems with `<3` and `:'(`

[image: smiles]

Comment: Can you post `$string`?

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand, I'd store those like `':)' => "<img src....",` and use [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to save yourself some sanity when moving items around in those lists.

Comment: Or use `strtr()` with the associative array.

Comment: My guess is that in your string you have the values `&rsquo;` and `&lt;`

Comment: @Barmar its just smiles mess :D `:):angel::angry:8-):'(:ermm::D<3:(:O:P;):alien::blink::blush::cheerful::devil::dizzy::getlost::happy::kissing::ninja::pinch::pouty::sick::sideways::silly::sleeping::unsure::woot::wassat:` , I tried to convert only <3 and only :'(, but it still didn't work. @castis yep, I thought about this just when I finished doing this code xD maybe will change it.

Comment: Works fine for me: http://ideone.com/TyxVuU I suspect @cmorrissey is correct.

Comment: '&lt;3' works now,  but ':&rsquo;(' does not

Comment: Haha, fixed! there was not ':&rsquo;(' , but ':&#039;(' in string :) thank you guys!